# Why does Windows will not allow me to paste multi-line text of PDF file to save the file?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I use Firefox and I have Adobe Reader plugin installed on it. When working with PDF files (opened in Firefox), I would like to save PDF documents by their titles. So, I copy the title of the PDF and then save the PDF in my desktop (in Windows 7). If the title spans to multiple lines (2 or 3), then Windows will only copy the first line. So when I paste it I have to complete by hand the rest of the title.

Say I have this PDF file http://www.frontiersin.org/files/pdf/Frontiers_Brochure.pdf and I would like to save it in my desktop as "Publishing the most-cited journals in their fields.pdf". So I copy the title and then I click on save document (in Adobe). When I paste it in the save as platform of Windows, I get "Publishing.pdf" because the title I copied is of the form

"Publishing

the most-cited

journals in their fields"

which has 3 lines.

As a solution, I should paste the title elsewhere (before clicking at save PDF document), on the address bar for example, and I can then copy-paste it to save the document.

Why this happen nad how to fix this, if possible?

NB. With chrome and its PDF plugin, the same happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, the newline or carriagereturn characters are illegal in file names. Therefore, you have to eliminate them.

Comment: So, there is no way to copy multi-line to rename a file? I have to copy-paste elsewhere and then rename?

Comment: Manually, just with copy/past, no. Unless you can find an utility which can remove illegal characters from your clipboard. This would, however, be outside of the scope of PDF and PDF viewers.

Answer (score 0):

This is just workaround.

Just copy the desired text and paste it into firefox www address bar. You will see that address bar is immune to line breaks. Then Ctrl+a and ctrl+c.